# Can I use functions from one PowerShell task in another task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am building a deployment pipeline and I'd like to import a module of functions so that I can reuse them in different steps. Is there a way to define functions in one task and then use them in a different task?

If I have to use modules for re-usability, where should I put that module so the pipeline finds it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each PowerShell Task in your pipeline is a different process, so it looses all contextual information from one task to another.
However, things that are persisted on the disk and environment variables are kept during the whole pipeline job execution.
So **if your module is available on the PowerShell gallery**, you could `Install-Module modulename -Scope CurrentUser` which will install the module for the current user (you can't install modules globally on hosted agents).
You'll then be able to use it in every step as long as you import it.
**If your functions are not a module available on the gallery**, you can perfectly store them on the repository (let's say in a `scripts` folder) and execute them as is.
If they are to be used in multiple repositories and you want to avoid duplicating the scripts, you can store them in a dedicated repository and leverage [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources) in your pipeline.